# SwiftData crash in preview: "... failed to find currently active container for ..."

Tags: swift, swift-data, xcode-previews

I'm getting a crash in the preview canvas only - runs fine in the simulator.

> Fatal error in ModelContainer.swift at line 144 - failed to find a currently active container for Book.

Running Xcode 15.3, and iOS 17.4.

**Main**

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct SwiftDataSandboxApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(for: Book.self, inMemory: true)
    }
}
```

**ContentView**

```
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query var books: [Book]

    @State private var showingAddScreen = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
           Text("Count: \(books.count)")
               .navigationTitle("Bookworm")
               .toolbar {
                   ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                       Button("Add Book", systemImage: "plus") {
                           showingAddScreen.toggle()
                       }
                   }
               }
               .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddScreen) {
                   AddBookView()
               }
       }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

**AddBookView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddBookView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    @State private var title = ""
    @State private var author = ""
    @State private var rating = 3
    @State private var genre = "Fantasy"
    @State private var review = ""

    let genres = ["Fantasy", "Horror", "Kids", "Mystery", "Poetry", "Romance", "Thriller"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Name of book", text: $title)
                    TextField("Author's name", text: $author)

                    Picker("Genre", selection: $genre) {
                        ForEach(genres, id: \.self) {
                            Text($0)
                        }
                    }
                }

                Section("Write a review") {
                    TextEditor(text: $review)

                    Picker("Rating", selection: $rating) {
                        ForEach(0..<6) {
                            Text(String($0))
                        }
                    }
                }

                Section {
                    Button("Save") {
                        let newBook = Book(title: title, author: author, genre: genre, review: review, rating: rating)
                        modelContext.insert(newBook)
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Add Book")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    AddBookView()
}
```

**Book**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
class Book {
    var title: String
    var author: String
    var genre: String
    var review: String
    var rating: Int

    init(title: String, author: String, genre: String, review: String, rating: Int) {
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.genre = genre
        self.review = review
        self.rating = rating
    }
}
```

I've also tried initiatin `modelContainer` differenly in the main app file as I found in other suggestions online. This did not change the crash.

```
@main
struct SwiftDataSandboxApp: App {

  let modelContainer: ModelContainer

  init() {
    do {
      modelContainer = try ModelContainer(for: Book.self)
    } catch {
      fatalError("Could not initialize ModelContainer")
    }
  }

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      VStack {
        ContentView()
      }
    }
    .modelContainer(modelContainer)
  }
}
```

Any help is apprectiated!!

Comment: #Preview need a container too

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/how-to-use-swiftdata-in-swiftui-previews

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you, not sure how I missed that page but that was definitely the answer. Is there a way to give you credit for the answer?